# antlr tokenizer starts with the last token

Tags: antlr4

I have the following grammar:

```
grammar Aligner;

line
    :   emptyLine
    |   codeLine
    ;

emptyLine
    :   ( KW_EMPTY KW_LINE )?
        ( EOL | EOF )
    ;

codeLine
    :   KW_LINE COLON
        indent
        CODE
        ( EOL | EOF )
    ;

indent
    :   absolute_indent
    |   relative_indent
    ;

absolute_indent
    :   NUMBER
    ;

relative_indent
    :   sign NUMBER
    ;

sign
    :   PLUS
    |   MINUS
    ;

COLON:                  ':';
MINUS:                  '-';
PLUS:                   '+';

KW_EMPTY:               'empty';
KW_LINE:                'line';

NUMBER
    :   DIGIT+
    ;

EOL
    :   ('\n' | '\r\n')
    ;

SPACING
    :   LINE_WS -> skip
    ;

CODE
    :   (~('\n' | '\r'))+
    ;

fragment
DIGIT
    :   '0'..'9'
    ;

fragment   
LINE_WS
    :   ' '
    |   '\t'
    |   '\u000C'
    ;
```

when I try to parse - `empty line` I receive error: `line 1:0 no viable alternative at input 'empty line'`. When I debug what is going on, the very first token is from type CODE and includes the whole line.

What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ANTLR will try to match the longest possible token. When two lexer rules match the same string of a given length, the first rule that appears in the grammar wins.

You rule `CODE` is basically a catch-all: it will match whole lines of text. So here ANTLR has the choice of matching `empty line` as one single token of type `CODE`, and as no other rule can produce a token of length 10, the `CODE` rule will consume the whole line.

You should rewrite the `CODE` rule to make it match only what you mean by a code. Right now it's way too broad.